# android : how can i fetch my selected id in my sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, fetch

I want to fetch some data from DB. I don't get any error messages. Here is the code that doesn't work:

database helper:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "recipename";
    public static final String KEY_INGRDNAME = "ingrdname";

    public static final String MENU_ID = "_id";
    public static final String RECIPE_NAME = "recipe";

    private static final String MYDATABASE = "recipebook.db";
    private static final int VERSION = 1;

    private static final String RECIPE_TABLE = "recipe";
    private static final String MENU_TABLE = "menu";
    static final String viewrecipe ="viewrecipe";

     public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, MYDATABASE, null, VERSION);
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+RECIPE_TABLE+" ("+KEY_ROWID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + KEY_NAME+ " TEXT, " + KEY_INGRDNAME+ "TEXT )");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+MENU_TABLE+" ("+MENU_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                RECIPE_NAME +" INTEGER NOT NULL ,FOREIGN KEY ("+RECIPE_NAME+") REFERENCES "+RECIPE_TABLE+" ("+KEY_ROWID+"));");

        db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW "+viewrecipe+
                " AS SELECT "+RECIPE_TABLE +"."+KEY_NAME+""+
            " FROM "+MENU_TABLE+" JOIN "+RECIPE_TABLE+
            " ON "+MENU_TABLE+"."+RECIPE_NAME+" ="+RECIPE_TABLE+"."+KEY_ROWID
        );
        //Inserts pre-defined departments
        InsertRecipe(db);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+MENU_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+RECIPE_TABLE);

        db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS "+viewrecipe);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    void InsertRecipe(SQLiteDatabase db) {          
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, "Beef tapa");
        values.put(KEY_INGRDNAME, " 2 pounds beef round or chuck, sliced thinly against the grain , 1/2 cup lemon juice, 1/3 cup soy sauce , 2 tablespoons sugar, 1/4 teaspoon ground black pepper, 1 head garlic, minced, Canola or any cooking oil for frying " );
        db.insert(RECIPE_TABLE, KEY_NAME, values);

        values.put(KEY_NAME, "Bulalo");
        values.put(KEY_INGRDNAME, " 6 - 7 pounds Beef Shanks with Bone Marrow, 1 head Garlic, cut, 1 large Onion, cubed, 2 Carrots, roughly cut, 2 stalks Celery, roughly cut, 1 teaspoon Whole Peppercorns, 1 tablespoon Salt, Leeks (optional), 2 - 3 Potatoes, cubed, 2 Corn on the cob, cut in 1 1/2 inch, 2 stalks Pechay or Bok Choy, 1 gallon Water, or enough to cover meat" );
        db.insert(RECIPE_TABLE, KEY_NAME, values);

        values.put(KEY_NAME, "Caldereta");
        values.put(KEY_INGRDNAME, "2 pounds Beef, cut in 2 inch cubes, 1/2 head garlic, minced, 1/2 cup vinegar, 2 teaspoon salt, 2 pieces bay leaf (dahon ng laurel), enough water to cover the beef, 1/2 head garlic, minced, 1 medium onion, chopped, 1 small can tomato sauce, 6 small potatoes, quartered, 2-3 small Chili pepper, cut finely, 1 red bell pepper, cut in strips, 1/2 cup Green peas(optional), 1/2 cup Pickle Relish, 1 small can Liver Spread, 1/2 cup Olives, Salt and Pepper to taste, 2 teaspoon sugar, 2 tablespoons cooking oil, for sauteing, LIVER GRAVY INGREDIENTS (Optional), 1/2 pound beef liver, ground, 2 tablespoons vinegar, 2 tablespoons breadcrumbs, 1 cup beef broth, salt and pepper.");
        db.insert(RECIPE_TABLE, KEY_NAME, values);

        values.put(KEY_NAME, "Kare kare");
        values.put(KEY_INGRDNAME, "2 pounds Oxtail, cut in 1 thickness,1 pound beef tripe (tuwalya), pressure cooked, cut into 2 squares (optional), 1/2 pound string beans, sliced in 3 lengths, 2 pcs. eggplants, sliced in 3 wedges, 1 banana bud or heart(puso ng saging), sliced in strips(optional), 6 stalks Bok Choy(Pechay), leaves and stalk separated, cut in 2 lengths, 1/2 cup peanut butter, dissolved in 1 cup beef broth, 1/4 cup toasted rice, powdered, dissolved in 1/2 cup beef broth, 5 cups beef broth, 2 tablespoons achuete seeds, 1/4 cup cooking oil,3 cloves garlic, minced, 1 medium onion, chopped, 1 tablespoon salt,1 tablespoon sugar, 1/4 teaspoon pepper, Sauteed Shrimp Paste");
        db.insert(RECIPE_TABLE, KEY_NAME, values);

        values.put(KEY_NAME, "Mechado");    
        values.put(KEY_INGRDNAME, "    2 pounds Top or Bottom Round Beef Roast, cut in 2-3 inch tubes, 1/2 pound Pork Fat, cut in strips, 5-6 Potatoes, cubed, 4 cloves Garlic, minced, 1 medium Onion, chopped, 1/3 cup Vinegar, 1 - 2 cups water, 2 tablespoons Soy Sauce, 1 small can tomato sauce, 1 pc. Bay Leaf, Salt and Pepper,3 tablespoons cooking oil");
        db.insert(RECIPE_TABLE, KEY_NAME, values);
    }


    public String getRecipe(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.query(RECIPE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_ROWID }, KEY_ROWID + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        String contact = new String(c.getString(id));
            // return contact
        return contact;
    }
```

my java class. I want it to fetch data on `textview`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class menucategory1a1 extends Activity {

    private DatabaseHelper db;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.beef1);

        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.beeftapaingredients);
    text.setText(db.getRecipe(0));

        Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
            public void onClick(View view) { 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), menucategory1a1a.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check your database to see if there is data in there?

Comment: I haven't check it yet , since this is my first time making a database in android.....and I don't know where can I see my database, I just follow all the tutorials I searched and this is the result of it , sad it is epic fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here    `String contact = new String(c.getString(id));`  The getString(id) takes a column index, not the id of the row you were trying to pick.

Comment: I tried to put   menu contact = new menu (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),
              c.getString(1), c.getString(2));
   // return contact
   return contact;
  }} (and added menu in menu class for the constructors and tested it and said that i got a problem in textview so i put text.setText((CharSequence) db.getRecipe(0)); and run it again and the green debug hypen the  TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.beeftapaingredients);)

Comment: The other problem is your get call.  You're doing a search by rowid, with a hard coded rowid of 0 coming from your activity.  I'm not sure that's a valid value-  rowids may start at 1, or even a random starting point for all I know.  I wouldn't assume they start at 0.

Comment: Good day sir , I ve changed my codes but I still have an errors can you check  what's the errors on my code again?  here is the link sir, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062062/android-how-can-i-retrieve-my-desire-data-in-my-database hope you an help me again thanks